# Move Data from UserControls to a Listbox

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7

I am working on Window Phone 7.5. I have to fetch values from user controls and show them in a ListBox in multiple columns.  Whenever a user submits data the values from all the controls will show in a list box each in different columns.

Answer (score 1):

You should use Data Binding.

Read, and do all the examples here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750612.aspx

and you'll be well prepared to do what you want.